# How to create a Matrix in SQL / How to Pivot with a lot of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a simple Invoice table that has each item sold and the date it was sold.

I want to create a matrix where on the left is a list of item numbers going from top to bottom and on the top is a list of weeks from 1-52 and in the middle is how much of that item was sold in that week.

Here is what I have so far. It is just the week, the item number, and how much it was sold in that week as a simple list.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT 
    Week
    ,Item_Number
    ,Color_Code
    ,Count(1) Touches
    FROM (

        SELECT

         DATEPART (year, I.Date_Invoiced) Year
        ,DATEPART (month, I.Date_Invoiced) Month
        ,DATEPART (week, I.Date_Invoiced) Week
        ,DATEPART (day, I.Date_Invoiced) Day
        ,I.Invoice_Number
        ,I.Customer_Number
        ,I.Warehouse_Code
        ,S.Pack_Type
        ,S.Quantity_Per_Carton
        ,S.Inner_Pack_Quantity
        ,ID.Item_Number
        ,ID.Color_Code
        ,ID.Quantity
        ,case when s.Pack_Type='carton' then id.Quantity/s.Quantity_Per_Carton when  s.Pack_Type='Inner Poly'  then id.Quantity/s.Inner_Pack_Quantity end  qty
        ,ID.Line_Number

        FROM    Invoices I
                LEFT JOIN Invoices_Detail ID on I.Company_Code = ID.Company_Code and I.Division_Code = ID.Division_Code and I.Invoice_Number = ID.Invoice_Number
                LEFT JOIN Style S on I.Company_Code = S.Company_Code and I.Division_Code = S.Division_Code and ID.Item_Number = S.Item_Number and ID.Color_Code = S.Color_Code

        WHERE   1=1
                AND (I.Company_Code = @LocalCompanyCode OR @LocalCompanyCode IS NULL)  
                AND (I.Division_Code = @LocalDivisionCode OR @LocalDivisionCode IS NULL)
                AND (I.Warehouse_Code = @LocalWarehouse OR @LocalWarehouse IS NULL)
                AND (S.Pack_Type = @LocalPackType OR @LocalPackType IS NULL)
                AND (I.Customer_Number = @LocalCustomerNumber OR @LocalCustomerNumber IS NULL)
                AND (I.Date_Invoiced Between @LocalFromDate And @LocalToDate)
                AND Inner_Pack_Quantity > 1
    ) T
    GROUP BY Week, Item_Number, Color_Code

) TT
ORDER BY Week, Item_Number
```

And some sample data:

```
+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| Week |   Item_Number   | Color_Code | Touches |
+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 11073900LRGMO   |      02000 |       7 |
|    1 | 11073900MEDMO   |      02000 |       9 |
|    2 | 1114900011BMO   |      38301 |      62 |
|    2 | 1114910012BMO   |      21701 |     147 |
|    2 | 1114910012BMO   |      38301 |     147 |
|    2 | 1114910012BMO   |      46260 |     147 |
|    3 | 13MK430R03R     |      00101 |       2 |
|    3 | 13MK430R03R     |      10001 |       2 |
|    3 | 13MK430R03R     |      65004 |       8 |
|    3 | 13MK430R03S     |      00101 |       2 |
|    3 | 13MK430R03S     |      10001 |       2 |
+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

I was looking at some guides on how to Pivot but they all seem to say that you need to specify each column name which in my case would be very hard since I have hundreds of items and I don't know what they all will be beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is using dynamic queries to get this done, then you wouldn't have to know in advance how many weeks are included in the report. I used your sample data to demonstrate this using SQL Server 2014, I also added some extra records for effect. If you don't know how pivot tables work then this is going to be hard to follow but play with the example and you'll get it in no time. The first dynamic statement, by way of a cursor, builds the list of columns for your pivot then concatenates them together with the rest of the query you'll need for the pivot. Lastly the whole thing gets executed.

```
-- I created a temp table out of your sample data to show how the dynamic query will work,
-- also added some extra data to demonstrate that you don't need to know the number of weeks in advance.
-- You should replace the the temp table with your query as a table or store the results in a global temp.
-- Notice that the temp table is global this is because the dynaimic queries will run on thier own 
-- session and not have access to the temp if you declare it as #dynPivot instead use ##dynPivot 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##dynPivot') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE ##dynPivot
    END 
GO
-- Create temp
CREATE TABLE ##dynPivot( 
    [Week] INT,
    Item_Number VARCHAR(50),
    Color_Code VARCHAR(50),
    Touches INT
)
-- populate temp with sample data
INSERT INTO ##dynPivot([Week], Item_Number, Color_Code, Touches)
VALUES (1, '11073900LRGMO','02000',7), (1, '11073900MEDMO', '02000',9), (2, 
'1114900011BMO', '38301',62), (2, '1114910012BMO', '21701',147), (2, '1114910012BMO', '38301',147), (2, '1114910012BMO', '46260',147), 
(3, '13MK430R03R', '00101',2), (3, '13MK430R03R', '10001',2), (3, '13MK430R03R', '65004',8), 
(3, '13MK430R03S', '00101',2), (3, '13MK430R03S', '10001',2), (4, '13MK430R03S', '10001',2), (5, '13MK430R03S', '10001',6),
(9, '13MK430R03S', '10001',2),(10, '13MK430R03S', '10001',1),(6, '13MK430R03S', '10001',1),(3, '13MK430R03S', '10001',9),
(4, '13MK430R03R', '00101',2), (8, '13MK430R03R', '10001',126), (7, '13MK430R03R', '65004',8),
(10, '1114910012ACB', '21701',147), (20, '1114910012XYZ', '38301',17), (12, '1114910012BMO', '46260',14)

-- Build the two dynaimc queries
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @sql = 'DECLARE @innerSql VARCHAR(MAX) = '''' 
DECLARE @week VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @selectList VARCHAR(500) = ''''
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT[week]) FROM ##dynPivot)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT [week] FROM ##dynPivot GROUP BY [week] ORDER BY [week]
OPEN c 
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @week
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @counter > 1
            BEGIN
                SET @selectList = @selectList + ''['' + @week + ''], ''
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @selectList = @selectList + ''['' + @week + '']''
            END
        SET @counter = @counter - 1
        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @week
    END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
SET @innerSql = @innerSql + ''SELECT Item_Number, '' + @selectList + '' FROM (SELECT [Week], Item_Number, Touches FROM ##dynPivot) AS DataSorce'' + 
'' PIVOT (SUM(Touches) FOR [week] IN ('' + @selectList + '')) AS PT''
EXEC(@innerSql)'
--Execute them
EXEC(@sql)

-- You should get the following results
-- Item_Number      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      12      20
-- 11073900LRGMO    7       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
-- 11073900MEDMO    9       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
-- 1114900011BMO    NULL    62      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
-- 1114910012ACB    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    147     NULL    NULL
-- 1114910012BMO    NULL    441     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    14      NULL
-- 1114910012XYZ    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    17
-- 13MK430R03R      NULL    NULL    12      2       NULL    NULL    8       126     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
-- 13MK430R03S      NULL    NULL    13      2       6       1       NULL    NULL    2       1       NULL    NULL
```